# Angular: How to subscribe to constantly changing data variable in service as data source for Angular Material Table

Tags: javascript, angular

I need some guidance please. How can I subscribe to a constantly updated variable (searchData - the value of my search results) as data source used in an Angular Material Table?

I have a `table-datasource.ts` file where I would like to subscribe to the search results of a `search.service.ts` data variable.

I think I can use `BehaviorSubject`, but I am not sure how to implement this correctly.

**I have the following basic setup in my `table-datasource.ts file`:**

```
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<SearchRecord>();

ngOnInit() {
  this.dataSource.data = this.searchService.searchData; // this is where I would like to subscribe to the data changes
}
```

**This is my search.service:**

```
search(): Observable<SearchRecord[]>  {

return this.http
  .get<SearchRecord[]>(this.baseUrl + searchUrl + birthdate + partytype, { headers: httpHeaders })
  .pipe(
    retry(3),
    map((responseData: SearchRecord[]) => {
      let response: SearchRecord[] = [];
      this.searchData = responseData; // This is the variable I would like to subscribe to
      response = responseData;

      return response;
    }),
    catchError(errorRes => {
      // Send to analytics server
      return throwError(errorRes);
    }));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Herewith my solution:

In my service I set up my data variable to be new `BehaviorSubject`, and implemented the `.next()` emitter on my returned data. Then I simply subscribed to the service variable in my component.

**Set up variable to be BehaviorSubject in service:**

```
searchData = new BehaviorSubject<SearchRecord[]>(null);
```

**Returned data call .next in my method call in my service:**

```
map((responseData: SearchRecord[]) => {
  let response: SearchRecord[] = [];
  this.searchData.next(responseData); // Call .next on returned data
  response = responseData;

  return response;
}),
```

**Subscribe to service variable in my Component:**

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.searchService.searchData.subscribe(data => {
      this.dataSource.data = data;
    });
  }
```

I hope this will help someone else!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a stackblitz example:
https://angular-lzdd2p.stackblitz.io

Based on https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples, "Table retrieving data through HTTP".

If you have an Observable data source, like this:

```
  getData(): Observable<{items: MyData[]}> {
    return new Observable(subscriber => {
      this.myNext(subscriber);
    });;
  }
```

And a property for the data-table in your class, like this

```
data: MyData[] = [];
```

You only need to subscribe to it:

```
this.getData().subscribe(data =>
  {this.data = data.items; this.resultsLength = data.items.length; });
```